# Defining findbugs detector using the existing plugins

Tags: java, static-analysis, checkstyle, findbugs

I'm trying to figure out how could I implement a detector using findbugs.

Also I don't want to create a plugin since findbugs already has this functionality.

I need my detector to check if all the calls to ClassName.getConnection() are matched by ClassName.freeConnection().

Comment: As an aside, you probably want to implement the interface AutoCloseable on whatever this class is.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have your answer in this link:

https://vasileirimia.wordpress.com/2015/07/14/addind-custom-constraints-called-obligations-to-findbugs/

Good luck !

Comment: you can also check out this link: https://vasileirimia.wordpress.com/2015/07/17/writing-your-own-findbugs-plugin-obligation-detector/